# Switch Element Type from Character to Numeric?

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have 3D matrix with numbers, but R treat numeric data as character, somehow. Files I load are numeric vectors. But once I put them into 3D vector, all data numbers shows up as "character" like this:

```
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  
  [1,] "3.79" "3.79" "2.33" "2.33" "2.79" "2.79"
  [2,] "3.79" "3.79" "2.33" "2.33" "2.79" "2.79"
  [3,] "3.02" "3.02" "4.94" "4.94" "4.33" "4.33"
  [4,] "3.02" "3.02" "4.94" "4.94" "4.33" "4.33"
  [5,] "4.25" "4.25" "4.06" "4.06" "4.98" "4.98"
  [6,] "4.25" "4.25" "4.06" "4.06" "4.98" "4.98"
  [7,] "4.25" "4.25" "4.06" "4.06" "4.98" "4.98"
  [8,] "2.07" "2.07" "2.09" "2.09" "2.92" "2.92"
```

but before I put in 3D matrix, data shows like this:

```
[39965] 3.68230769 3.68230769 3.68230769 2.96454545
[39969] 2.96454545 3.93600000 3.93600000 3.93600000
[39973] 3.67769231 3.67769231 3.67769231 5.12750000
[39977] 5.12750000 5.12750000 3.05083333 3.05083333
[39981] 3.05083333 1.94166667 1.94166667 1.69000000
[39985] 1.69000000 1.69000000 2.01769231 2.01769231
[39989] 2.01769231 3.05692308 3.05692308 3.05692308
[39993] 3.72916667 3.72916667 3.72916667 2.65454545
[39997] 2.65454545 2.45583333 2.45583333 2.45583333
```

Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1: length(precipitation)) {
    precip <- read.csv(precipitation[i])
    precip[is.na(precip)] <- 0

    precip2<- precip[,-1]
    precip3<-as.vector(unlist(precip2))
    prep_data[,,i]<-matrix(precip3,ncol=200,nrow=200)
}
```

Is it possible to add some coding to fix this problem, so all my 3D matrix elements are numeric, not "numeric".

Comment: `as.numeric()` will convert them to numeric. It's hard to know from the code you provided when they got converted to character in the first place.

Comment: @shujaa Has the right answer.  If you have non-numeric (or ".") characters, you may need to regex out the garbage or use `taRifx::destring`.

Comment: You didn't tell us where `prep_data` came from, but it would appear that it was a character array, hence the conversion.

Comment: @shujaa, you my lifesaver!!! Worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.numeric` to convert something to numeric. In general, `as.class` converts to that class (numeric, character, factor, Date, data.frame, matrix, and many many more).

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce input data to a particular class with the colClasses argument. The code below which might be substituted for the read.csv call in your code will generate warnings if it encounters non-numeric entries, but the good data will be ensured to be numeric:

```
precip <- read.csv(precipitation[i], colClasses="numeric" )
```

Comment: But my data is numeric before I use code: prep_data[,,i]<-matrix(precip3,ncol=200,nrow=200). But after this part is run, it becomes character. Do you know anything I can do?

Comment: If I put your code, it will get error: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"1"'

Comment: If you will post the first few lines as they appear in a text editor we can probably set up the input arguments properly.